# Adding to existing value in mySQL database from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my database with the following columns:

```
username - course - assignment1 - assignment2 - assignment3 - participation - total
```

I am using a form that submits these values to the database. What I am trying to do is take the value that's already exists the participation column for the username that was inputed in the form and add the new inputed value to it. (participation = participation + userinput)

How do I do this in PHP after connecting to the database?

Comment: Could we see how you're connecting to the db, and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You use an `update` statement for this:

```
update table
    set participation = participation + @UserInput
    where username = @userName;
```

Of course, you should use parameters for these values in the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Calling back the column name invoque his own value.

```
$query = "Update table set participation = participation +".intval($_POST['userinput'])." where username ='".$_POST['username']."'"; 
mysqli_query($query);
```